# Azure Logic App: Is it possible to send a XML File via HTTP Request and then save it as an .xml File on OneDrive

Tags: xml, httprequest, azure-logic-apps, onedrive

I have been trying to create an Azure Logic App, which takes an .xml File and saves/creates it in my OneDrive Account (I do not know a lot about http requests, json files or anything similar).
At the time I'm writing this, I've got the connection to my OneDrive to save an **empty** .xml File.

Now I'll need your help for saving the file **with raw data**.
The xml structure I would want to save, is always split into multiple parts.

The **NAV_Header** part only appears **once**, yet the **NAV_Line** part can appear **multiple times**.

```
<Root>
  <NAV_Header>
    <Customer>BIBA</Customer>
    <Stylesheet>NAV_CH_PROD/item-label.xsl</Stylesheet>
    <Separate_FOP_Config>0</Separate_FOP_Config>
    <User_ID>BOSSINFO\SMUELLER</User_ID>
    <Output_Option>0</Output_Option>
    <Output_Path />
    <Printer_Name />
    <Windows_Printer>0</Windows_Printer>
  </NAV_Header>
  <NAV_Line>
    <Item_Description>Kolben DN 10-15 H-PVC</Item_Description>
    <Item_No>123456789012</Item_No>
      <Item_No_Lbl>Artikel Nr.: </Item_No_Lbl>
    <Order_No>51062579</Order_No>
    <Order_No_Lbl>Bestell Nr.: </Order_No_Lbl>
    <Amount>275</Amount>
    <Amount_Lbl>Amount: </Amount_Lbl>
  </NAV_Line>
</Root>
```

Thanks to everyone that can help me.

Comment: What language are you doing the request?  You can parse file in many different languages including a power shell script.

Comment: That would be C# or AL, I can implement both. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-programming-in-al

Comment: Easy with XML Linq to parse the xml in c#.  What format do you want the output.

Comment: The format doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication40
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.csv";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(OUTPUT_FILENAME);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(INPUT_FILENAME);

            XElement xNavHeader = doc.Root.Element("NAV_Header");

            string[] navHeaders =  {"Customer", "Stylesheet", "Separate_FOP_Config", "User_ID", "Output_Option", "Output_Path", "Printer_Name", "Windows_Printer"};

            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", navHeaders));
            string[] navData = navHeaders.Select(x => (string)xNavHeader.Element(x)).ToArray();
            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", navData));

            string[] navLineHeaders = { "Item_Description", "Item_No", "Item_No_Lbl", "Order_No", "Order_No_Lbl", "Amount", "Amount_Lbl" };
            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", navLineHeaders));

            foreach(XElement xNAV_Line in doc.Root.Descendants("NAV_Line"))
            {
                string[] navLineData = navLineHeaders.Select(x => (string)xNAV_Line.Descendants(x).FirstOrDefault()).ToArray();
                writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", navLineData));
            }

            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();

        }

    }
}
```